# Very Confusing MethodNotAllowedHttpException on a put request laravel

Tags: php, forms, laravel-5, put, laravel-blade

So far all attempts to modify the routing methods have failed.

Been following some documentation on laravel restful controllers and have one set up to do basic editing and adding of items to a database. It was going well till I hit the snag on... well I'm not sure what precisely is triggering the problem, but basically, everything works till I hit submit on the form and then it's Game Over.

Normally I'd be able to diagnose this by checking to see if I'm using the right call, or made a spelling mistake or something. But this is a new request for me, so I can't quite debug where the problem is coming from.

This is the error those who know what to look for. In full [here](http://pastebin.com/RkmSnNZW).

```
MethodNotAllowedHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 218:
```

My routes are [pasted here](http://pastebin.com/scD4uMWB). 
A printout of the routes [is here](http://pastebin.com/4wpMsz4k):

Controller:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

use App\Http\Requests\ContactFormRequest;
use App\UserEdit;
use DB;
use App\Http\Requests;

class EditUserController extends Controller
{

    public function index()
    {
        $array = UserEdit::all()->toArray();
        return view('UserEntry', compact('array'));
    }


    public function create()
    {
        $id = UserEdit::find(715)->toArray();
        return view('NewUser', compact('id'));
    }


    public function store(UserFormRequest $request)
    {
        //$user = new UserEdit([
        //    'name'=>$request->get('First_Name'),
        //    'email'=>$request->get('email'),
        //    'username'=>$request->get('name')
        //]);
        //
        //$user->save();
        //return \Redirect::route('users')->with('message', 'Nice Work.');
    }


    public function show($id)
    {
        try {
         $array = UserEdit::findorFail($id)->toArray();
         return view('UserEdit')->with('array', $array);

         } catch(\Exception $e) {
             return \Redirect::route('users.index')
                ->withMessage('This user does not exist');
         }

    }


    public function edit($id)
    {
        $user = UserEdit::findorFail($id);
        return view('EditUser')->with('user',$user);
    }


    public function update($id, UserFormRequest $request)
    {
       $user = UserEdit::findorFail($id);

       $user->update([
           'name' => $request->get('name'),
           'email' => $request->get('email')
       ]);

       return \Redirect::route('users.edit', [$user->id])->with('message', 'Details Updated!');
    }


    public function destroy($id)
    {
        //
    }
}
```

The Blade [is here](http://pastebin.com/L1h2PrYV).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like after sorting out the routes, the issue fell to a bad capitalisation. $user->id should have been $user->ID.

Answer (score 1):

i think you are using model in form.try this

```
 {{ Form::open(['method' => 'put',  'route'=>['users.update', $user->id], 'class'=>'form']) }}
```

As per your route list and route put doesnt taking id so you get method not found exception

```
PUT users/{user}    App\Http\Controllers\EditUserController@update
```

instead of using resouce just type each route for each method

```
Route::put('users/{user}', 'EditUserController @update');
```

Comment: Yeah, laravel has form model binding, which I'm using to prefill the data.

Comment: @show route resource list .you get  using php artisan routes

Comment: Thanks for the help! But I don't quite follow how put users/{user} isn't taking id, as just to get to the form to make the edit requires the same route in edit users/{user}/edit, which is the assigned user's id. Or do you mean the put command itself can't take id?

Comment: Ok tested. Same result. I think there's a problem maybe with my controller code?

Answer (score 1):

if you have a hard time finding the solution the easiest solution is using

```
Route::any('users/{user}', 'UserEntryController@update');
```

this allow you to access this action with any method type
OR

```
Route::match(array('get', 'put'), 'users/{user}', 'UserEntryController@update');
```

so you need 2 method which are
get -> view
put -> submit update

you can just indicate which method type you want to be accessible with in this action

Comment: I tried manually setting the routes that are normally generated by the resource route and switched it off. Still got the same problem. First post updated to reflect this.